# How to uncheck the checkbox if it is in other component by using angular15

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with Angular15. I need help I struck with checkbox selection change.

**Scenario:** Based on the requirement I have a menu bar and Checkbox. Checkbox is coming from reusable component. This checkbox reusable component used in Menu bar page. By default, the check box is checked. But when I changed the menu bar options the checkbox should be unchecked.

[image]

**Problem:** In Above “Display” page the checkbox was checked. I want to Uncheck that checkbox by changing the menu options. If I click on “User” the checkbox should be uncheck. Every time while changing the menu options the checkbox should be unchecked if it is checked.

**selectionpage.component.html**

```
<p>Check Box Selection!</p>

<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked">Select All
```

Added a checkbox with Input parameter "isChecked".

**selectionpage.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-selectionpage',
  templateUrl: './selectionpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./selectionpage.component.scss']
})
export class SelectionpageComponent {
@Input() isChecked:boolean=true;
}
```

Now i am going to use this "Selectionpage" in "displaypage" to add checkbox.

**display-page.component.html**

```
<div class="tab-menu-container">
  <div class="tab-menu-wrapper">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let selectvalue of selectionContent">
      <div class="tab">
        <span (click)="changerArchiveType()" style="cursor: pointer;">{{ selectvalue }}</span>|
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
<app-selectionpage [isChecked]="SelectionChange"></app-selectionpage>
```

**display-page.component.scss**

```
.tab-menu-container{
    height: 56px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    .tab-menu-wrapper{
        width: 85%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        column-gap: 2rem;
        padding-top: 20px;

        .tab{
            width: fit-content;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 15px;
            line-height: 20px;
        }
    }
}
```

**display-page.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-display-page',
  templateUrl: './display-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display-page.component.scss'],
})
export class DisplayPageComponent {
  public selectionContent: Array<string> = [
    'User',
    'Admin',
    'SuperAdmin',
    'Seller',
  ];
  public SelectionChange:boolean=false;
  changerArchiveType() {
    this.SelectionChange=false;
    console.log("Checked:",this.SelectionChange)
  }
}
```

Now the page cointains "Menu bar " with options and checkbox.

If i changed the menu bar option the chekbox should be uncheck.It is happening first time after page load. But after that uncheck is not working by changing the menu.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised this ever works.  The reason is because the **SelectionChange** member variable in **DisplayPageComponent** never changes from its initial value of *false*.

You need to emit the change whenever the checkbox is checked by using an **EventEmitter** and **Output** decorator.  By convention, if you name the output variable the same name as the input variable with a *Change* suffix, then you can use the "banana in a box binding" like you did with the **ngModel** directive.

**selectionpage.component.ts**

Add the *isCheckedChange* event emitter.

```
export class SelectionpageComponent {
  @Input() isChecked: boolean = true;

  @Output() readonly isCheckedChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
}
```

**selectionpage.component.html**

Emit the *isCheckedChange* event when the *ngModel* changes.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" 
       (ngModelChange)="isCheckedChange.emit($event)">Select All
```

**display-page.component.html**

Use two-way binding for *isChecked* in outer component.

```
<app-selectionpage [(isChecked)]="SelectionChange"></app-selectionpage>
```